# Why such result

Tags: javascript

Unable to deduce the code execution

I've been doing some JS lately and below is the code that i got from a friend , now I thought that both of console logs will return the hello, but it wont, it returns a console log as object and for second console it returns undefined. Can anyone please care to explain why is this happening

```
function hello1(){
    return {
        bar : "hello"
    };
}

function hello2(){
    return 
    {
        bar : "hello"
    };
}

console.log(hello1());
console.log(hello2());
```

and the result was

```
   {bar: "hello"}
    undefined
```

Comment: `return` on its own line will terminate the function without returning anything

Comment: Ohh yea, it was a minor mistake but yea missed it, thanks